# C++-style vector - array of pointers or just array?

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, vector, containers

I'm writing simple template, vector-style class and I'm wondering, which way is better - to collect elements in normal array, or in array of pointers?
Second way should ensure faster copying of array, but needs more memory for pointers.

Am I right? Are there any other performance consequences?

Comment: If I were to use your array as Vector<T>, I expect copying that vector to also copy all its T elements. You may choose your storage internally, but while copying only pointers will be faster, it won't behave as expected.

Comment: There is no general answer. The performance difference will depend on the kind of elements: Are they equal in size? Are they small as pointers? Are they really LARGE?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm writing simple template, vector-style class and I'm wondering, which way is better - to collect elements in normal array, or in array of pointers?

All `std::vector<>` implementations choose a "normal array" -- a contiguous allocation of elements. Before considering performance, consider the semantics you need.

Using pointers can greatly complicate your implementation. Also, It would break `std::vector<>`'s guarantee that the elements are contiguously allocated.

Using pointers means more bookkeeping. Also, it will require additional allocations to maintain and indirection. A simpler structure of simple types can be faster to copy, although using underlying pointers has some advantages. Generally, you should favor the contiguous allocation as a default. If you find a great benefit for the case of pointers, use it in another type.

Also note that vector operations like moves and swaps can just be implemented by swapping the pointers to the array, so you can have pointer speed for some operations.

The existing vector design is a very good starting point.

The big benefit of contiguous allocations is that it is easy on the caches. Memory reads and writes are much faster than having elements' memory scattered all over the place.

Another point: The size of a pointer can be greater than one value/element. In that case, using pointers can multiply the memory demand.

> Second way should ensure faster copying of array, but needs more memory for pointers.

How so? You still need to copy elements and keep track of their lifetimes for proper semantics. In that case, a simple vector of `shared_ptr`s is an approach worth consideration, if your intention is to share the vector's elements. Generally, `shared_ptr` should be used very little, so you may want to rethink your design. There is absolutely nothing wrong using `std::vector<>`'s design as a starting point, as it is a great default.

Answer (score 1):

Why are you worrying about performance now? Also, a normal (C-style) array must have compile-time size, and also doesn't really need any fanc memory management, so you really don't have much of a choice.

Also, how would copy speed be related to the underlying data? If there are N bytes, either way would need to copy N bytes.

Comment: +1. And it is easier to copy N bytes that are close together and not scattered all over the place.

Comment: I was writing about dynamic allocated array. Just don't know if this should be either `(T**)` or `T*`.

Comment: @Krzysztof: it should be a `std::unique_ptr<T[]>`.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you want implement your own vector template? Don't do it, use one of the already existing [STL containers](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/) instead.

There is ***a lot more to do*** than just evaluate the "performance" relevance of pointer vs. flat data decisions.